# Trino approx_percentile get not exist result in large row set

Tags: function, presto, trino

We are trying to calculate percentiles using around 700 values with three decimal places.

When using the following sample dataset, we discovered that it is displaying values that do not exist in the actual dataset - easily found out becuase the decimal places are changed.

How can we obtain the data correctly?

After several trials and errors, we found that it correctly displays values up to 153, but starting from 154, the decimal places increase drastically, returning numbers that are not in the dataset.

here is our dataset sample and test query.

```
SELECT APPROX_PERCENTILE(x,  0.85)
--select count(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 59.533,49.879,51.488,64.360,56.315,54.706,54.706,54.706,54.706,54.706,54.706,49.879,48.270,57.924,54.706,64.360,54.706,46.661,51.488,49.879,54.706,59.533,56.315,62.751,61.142,53.097,53.097,54.706,54.706,51.488,51.488,46.661,56.315,45.052,64.360,57.924,54.706,54.706,54.706,64.360,51.488,51.488,64.360,51.488,49.879,54.706,53.097,70.796
) AS y(x));
```

Comment: TBH works for me on my local Trino installation.